# Set title to a simple Holoviews plot (python)

Tags: python, holoviews, holoviz

I have a simple Holoviews plot, in this case a scatter or points plot, but it has no title.
How do I add a title to this plot?

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh')

# create sample data    
data = np.random.normal(size=[50, 2])

# create simple plot (but it has no title)
hv.Points(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a title to your simple Holoviews plot by using argument **label='New title'** when creating your graph:

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh')

# create sample data    
data = np.random.normal(size=[50, 2])

# create simple plot and add title with label='New title just added'
hv.Points(data, label='New title just added')
```

If you would like to add a title to an Overlay plot, check this question + answer:
[Using Holoviews, how can I set a title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53288651/using-holoviews-how-can-i-set-a-title/58086187#58086187)

**Resulting plot with new title:**

[image: New title added to simple holoviews plot]